# How to make fast recompile time of react application in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

For the past 3/4 days, my react app take more than 3 to 5 minute to compile. My device has 4GB Ram 128 GB SSD and a 500GB hard disk. My project is medium size and I use VS Code editor. All other apps working perfectly. Please help how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could relate to eslint configuration, if so, you could try to add on the `.env` file `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true` and see if there's a considerable change in the recompilation time.

You could try and switch a package manager, `yarn` is recommended for fast compilation time if you are not using it already.